# Android: How to embed a class inside a textview of another xml?

Tags: android, embedded-resource

This is my layout:

```
<ListView>
   <TextView></TextView>
</ListView
```

This xml is the main.xml with main.java.  How can i embed intro.xml with intro.java into the `<Textview>?`

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not put `TextView` widgets inside of a `ListView` in a layout XML file. Also, you do not embed other widgets inside of a TextView.

To put things in a `ListView`, you need to use a `ListAdapter`, such as `ArrayAdapter` or `CursorAdapter`, depending on where your data is coming from.

You may wish to review [the `ListView` tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).